# Regex for an alphanumeric of 8 character

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I want a regex that matches this where A is alphanumeric. first four digits are fixed. 7PTCAAAA

Please help me

Examples:

7PTC69RT
7PTC67KM
7PTC689F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`7PTC[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}`

1. 7PTC matches the characters `7PTC` literally (case sensitive)
2. {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly `4` times

Try this [here](https://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/322)

Comment: thanks, one quick question, what if 7PTC should also be made as case insensitive?

Comment: Its normal case, but in your case, the `7PIC` be always fixed, so Its OK, @ParshoGiash. You also do the same work with `7PTC[\w\d]{4}`:  `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) (means al character from `a-z`,`A-Z`, all number from `0-9`, and , and underscore (`_`) character `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`).

Comment: You are not answering my question but supporting the other answer. I asked you, how am I suppose to change 7PTC to cater for 7pTc or 7ptC etc etc. Also, when \w already holds for number, why the \d?

Comment: 1. Use this: `7(P|p)(T|t)(C|c)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}`. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/323)

Comment: 2. If you dont use `\d`, The match data may be not a number. Do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get using the following regex:

7PTC[\w\d]{4}

Look at the example in the [link](https://regex101.com/r/2YNpkk/1)

Comment: your kind of answer always confuse layman like me as I dont know wha is w and d and you never explained with all possible values for w and d

Comment: Sorry @ParshoGiash, I thought you needed only the regex, but that was good explained in the other answer.